# Control an external process via a website

Tags: php, arduino, external-process

Lately I've grown some interest in electronics, more specifically the [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) platform. I've been soldering, and now I have created a device that can turn off my lights and other power related devices via this platform.

The next step is to be able to control the lights and stuff via a website.

The plan is to have a webserver ([Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)?) and run Apache with a PHP website. When I click a button (load a page with specific parameters, or some Ajax stuff...) I want to trigger an intermediate program (most likely a Java program) which actually talks to a controller Arduino board, which in turn will send the [RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) commands.

How can I make a website talk to an intermediate program?

Comment: How about exec or shell_exec?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [exec](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [shell_exec](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or any other process control function available to [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Answer (score 1):

You can stay entirely on the Arduino if you add an Ethernet shield. In the Arduino demo library there are examples of web hosting programs that you can use as a starting point.

For example, the Arduino can host a simple HTML page with a button in a form. Clicking that button requests a new URL to the Arduino with some value that you can parse for, and then conditionally toggle on or off a switch. There are some recent examples of people doing something similar with this, connecting an similar microcontroller with an [X10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29) [Firecracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_Firecracker) widget to monitor and control their home network. Here's [the description from hack-a-day](http://hackaday.com/2012/01/17/commandeer-x10-based-home-automation-with-your-favorite-microcontroller/).